# Where can I find hard data on students' reasons for being students?

Tags: reference-request, data, motivation

Have any studies been done of students' motives for being students at universities?

At one extreme there are those who want to study at a university in disregard of the disapproval of their parents and friends and everyone else. At an opposite extreme are those who are there *only* because of the expectations of others. And there are those who regard study at a university only as a price of a job they hope to get later.

Do any hard data exist on the proportions in each of these groups or on whether some other motivations exist?

Comment: Among the motivations, I think you overlooked those who become students at universities because they want to learn more about something of interest ;-)

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano : I didn't overlook those; they're included in my first group.

Comment: @MichaelHardy What if their parents and friends *approve* of them studying at university? Are they still in the first group?

Comment: Anecdotal motivations that I can't post as an answer: I'm the first person in my family to go to university. I am here because I don't like the stagnancy of the "working American". I don't like the little bubbles people put themselves in, unaware of the world around their immediate self. I'm here because I want to learn in order to affect change in life beyond *myself* - other countries, cultures, bettering the world and future young people. My best friend from high school wants to major in computer science to get a high-paying job so he can enjoy his life. So, **very** different motivations.

Comment: Seems funny to ask for hard data about something so inherently subjective....  // In the U.S., I think the two primary reasons young people go to college are (a) they hope it will make them more employable, and (b) they want to get out of the house.

Comment: You would also be surprised at the number of (new college) students who don't even know the reason why they are in school. In such a survey, "I am here because I don't know what else to do" option should be available.

Comment: There's plenty of people that simply find it a convenient life style (and thus often takes many more years than necessary to end university). You get money from parents & some scholarship. You have your school routine, and you have to study a bit to do at least a few exams a year for the scholarships, but you have a lot of free time and not that much responsibility... In some countries  (e.g. Italy, :sigh:) parents are *forced* to pay for your education if you don't have a job (and you are not obliged to find one).

Comment: This is also country-dependant. In some countries, higher education/professional schools are a way to dodge a conscription / land yourself a marriage.

Comment: When I entered uni, that was only easily possible for pupils having passed a certain route through the school system. Most of the pupils were strongly influenced by that fact. The question was not so much "if" but "what" to study, it didn't really occur to most of us to not study. It would have wasted a lot of school years; and the people not likely to engage with "mind stuff" in the first place likely were not in that part of the school system anyway (the other way around is not true, obviously).

Comment: That said, I would find the question more interesting if it was limited to those students actually finishing with any kind of degree.

Comment: @FixedPoint : I once shared an apartment with a student who was an army veteran whose reason for joining the army was something like "I am here because I don't know what else to do". Where he came from, joining the army was simply what one normally did after high school.

Comment: @Daerdemandt : During the Vietnam war, many Americans dodged conscription by being university students. It has been said that that was a major cause of grade inflation: professors didn't want to send student to war.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is an active area of inquiry in US academia, as market research for admissions departments and also as part of the larger investigation into student "success". Our dean likes to remind us that the main reason for going to college used to be "to get an education" but now it's "to get a job" (and thus we need to be more get-a-job focused). I don't actually know which study he's quoting, but an article out this month seems to support his contention.

Twenge and Donnelly have published a retrospective study of students entering college between 1971 and 2014 surveying the students' reasons for pursuing higher education. From the abstract:

> Millennials (in college 2000s–2010s) and Generation X (1980s–1990s)
>   valued extrinsic reasons for going to college (“to make more money”)
>   more, and anti-extrinsic reasons (“to gain a general education and
>   appreciation of ideas”) less than Boomers when they were the same age
>   in the 1960s–1970s.

(Twenge, J. M., & Donnelly, K. (2016). **Generational differences in American students’ reasons for going to college**, 1971–2014: The rise of extrinsic motives. *Journal Of Social Psychology, 156*(6), 620-629. doi:10.1080/00224545.2016.1152214)

Other articles that may be of interest (by no means an exhaustive list):

- Balloo, K., Pauli, R., & Worrell, M. (2015). **Undergraduates’ personal
  circumstances, expectations and reasons for attending university**.
  *Studies in Higher Education*. Advance online publication. doi:10.1080/03075079.2015.1099623
- Bui, K. V. T. (2002). **First-generation college students at a four-year university: background characteristics, reasons for pursuing higher education, and first-year experiences**. *College Student Journal, 36*(1). 3+.
- Kennett, D. J., Reed, M. J., & Lam, D. (2011). **The
  Importance of Directly Asking Students Their Reasons for Attending
  Higher Education**. *Issues in Educational Research, 21*(1) 65-74.
- Kennett, D. J., Reed, M. J., & Stuart A. S. (2013). **The impact of
  reasons for attending university on academic resourcefulness and
  adjustment**. *Active Learning in Higher Education, 14*(2). First
  published on June 10, 2015. doi:10.1177/1469787415589626
- Phinney, J. S.; Dennis, J.; Osorio, S. (2006). **Reasons to attend
  college among ethnically diverse college students**. *Cultural
  Diversity and Ethnic Minority Psychology, 12*(2).347-366. doi:
  10.1037/1099-9809.12.2.347
- Schultz, J., & Higbee, J. (2007). **Reasons for Attending College: The
  Student Point of View**. *Research and Teaching in Developmental
  Education, 23*(2), 69-76.

Answer (score 14):

It's quite likely that students entertain a collection of motivations (and de-motivators) rather than just one, so if such data exist they would probably be highly specific (to particular regions, economic conditions, personal circumstances and so on...) and difficult to extrapolate to other settings.

That said, in terms of general or potential categories, this [study of students in HUNGARY AND SERBIAN VOJVODINA](http://oaji.net/articles/2014/457-1420055524.pdf) lists the following motives, with interest, employability and economic reward covering most of the sample.

> - I wanted to study in this field because I am interested in it. **45%**
> - I believe it is easy to find a job in this field. **13%**
> - I believe I can make good money in this field. **12%**
> - I have professional connections in this field. **8%**
> - My parents decided that I should study in this course. **8%**
> - I had no other idea what to study. **4%**
> - I had no particular reasons. **3%**
> - This was the course I could afford financially. **3%**
> - This was the only available course nearby. **2%**
> - Other **2%**

Comment: Confirmed. I still have that collection of demotivators from my student days on my hard drive. (SCNR)

Comment: Your study seems to be about why students chose a certain field, not why they chose to study at all, which seems to be what the question was asking.